# Accessing parent elements with jQuery input names

Tags: jquery

Having trouble getting JQuery to access the parent form field 'inputStart's value  when a new value is chosen from the select field named inputStartMonth

What is strange is similar syntax is working elsewhere on the same site. I'm using the input's name and class because I repeat the same form (with a different id) multiple times on the same page.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the jquery code:

```
$('input[name=inputStartMonth]').change(function() {
var month = $(this).val();
$(this).parent().find('input[name=inputStart]').val(month);
});
```

Partial HTML:

```
<td><input name="inputStart" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="May '96">
<div class="startDateDrop hideThis dropForm">
<select name="inputStartMonth">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple problems. One, as others have mentioned, the parent of your select is a div, which is not the parent of your input. Second, your selector is using $('input[name=inputStartMonth]') it should be "select" not input. See: http://jsfiddle.net/sYFuY/

Comment: Thanks so much. I had tried using select as the input, but that alone didn't fix anything -- the closest command looks like it's going to be very helpful. Thanks for the example too.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute selectors should be quoted:

```
$('input[name="inputStartMonth"]')...
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the element you seem to be looking for, which *isn't* in any way a parent of the `select` element you're starting from, I'd suggest:

```
$(this).parent().prev('input[name="inputStart"]').val(month);
```

Also, according to the API documentation for the attribute-equals (`attribute="value"]`) selector quoting the value is mandatory.

References:

- [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Comment: Thank you -- just tried this as an alternate solution -- and it seems to work just as well as the example above with jQuery closest.

Answer (score 0):

Your partial html implies that the parent of the select is not an ancestor of the input, which means that the find will never find it. Try

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input[name=inputStart]').val(month);
```

Also, you are detecting `change` on an input by name `inputStartMonth`, which doesn't exist. You want:

```
$('select[name=inputStartMonth]').change(function() {
    var month = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('form').find('input[name=inputStart]').val(month);
});
```